# LayoutInflater Exception in Expandable List View

Tags: android, expandablelistview, layout-inflater, expandablelistadapter, expandable

I am trying to make an expandable list but getting error.

I just following all the things in the below Expandable list tutorial

Visit:- http://android-adda.blogspot.in/2011/06/custom-expandable-listview.html#comment-form

but i got a exception like this

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
 ComponentInfo{com.delightflavors/com.delightflavors.CategoryActivity}:
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class textview
```

Comment: Binary XML file line #13

Check if the textview defined at this line is correct. Does the eclipse / IntelliJ plugin complain about validation failures for the view layout ? Have you set a layout height and width ? Give us some more information.

Answer (score 0):

The blog post in the link you posted has serious problems with the usage of wrong case in XML files. It is `TextView` and `LinearLayout` and it is case-sensitive.